# Mount permanently a windows shared folder on linux

Tags: linux, mount, shared-folders

I have a little server with a shared partition called D. I'd like to mount it permanently on a local machine with Linux Ubuntu, in order to access them easily.
I have looked for similar questions, but i didn't find anything. Could somebody give me some hints how to do it?

Comment: You should either ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can find answers on [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/): https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=mount+windows+share

Or on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/): https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mount+windows+share

Answer (score 0):

See the [Ubuntu documentation form AutoFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs). The part you are instersted in is CIFS.

Comment: ...too tricky for me, can't do it without any help

Answer (score 0):

You should add a line like the following in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//<windows-machine-ip-address>/share  /mnt/winshare  cifs  username=<windows-user>,password=<user-password>,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0  0  0
```

where `/mnt/winshare` is the mount point in Linux

or better create a file (e.g /etc/.smbcreds) with 600 access rights:

```
username=msusername
password=mspassword
```

and add the following in fstab:

```
//<windows-machine-ip-address>/share  /mnt/winshare  cifs  credentials=/etc/.smbcreds,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I added the following line, but when i restart the system nothing happens //192.168.0.5/Dati%20(D) /mnt/winshare  cifs  username=Administrator,password=myPassword  0  0

Comment: I also tried as written here: http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/mounting-windows-smb-file-shares-using-cifs   and here http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html